# Query Projects Data of Recruiter LinkedIn profile from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, linkedin-api

I want to query LinkedIn Projects data from salesforce. I want to have the contacts associated with my linkedin project in salesforce. For example, I have a Recruiter Lite linkedIn Account and I have created a project and 100 contacts are associated with this project. I want to see these 100 linked contacts who are part of my project in salesforce. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn doesn't provide an API that would allow you to do this, nor are they happy when developers try to scrape their website.

https://developer.linkedin.com/

[LinkedIn Shuts Out Developers](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/02/12/linkedin-takes-aim-developers-plans-lock-apis/#.tnw_2UxoXnWr)